# Java8 convert list to map handling duplicate keys and manipulating values

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have the following data structure

```
public class Zones {

   private List<Zone> zones;
}

public class Zone {

  private int id;
  private String name;
  private List<Part> parts;
}

public class Part {
  private int id;
  private String name;
}
```

THis is my problem. I have with me an instance of  Zones, say z.

I want to stream z and do the following:
construct a map out of z with the following conditions:
if the key (based on the "Id" of the Zone) is new, then create an entry in the map with the key and the Zone. 
If the key is a duplicate, then append all "parts" of this duplicate zone into the existing zone's parts list.
In the end I should have a map with "Id" of the zone as the key and the zone as the value.

How can I do this in Java8 using streams?

Comment: *If the key is a duplicate, then append all "parts" of this duplicate zone into the existing zone's parts list.* ... what happens to the `name` in such a case for say `z1` and `z2` being `Zone` with the same id?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `Collectors.toMap()`, to make a new `Map` with zone id as the key and Zone as the value, if there is a duplicate then take the `List<Part>` from the second Zone and append it to the first one:

```
  Map<Integer, Zone> map = z.getZones().stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Zone::getId, Function.identity(), 
                             (zone1, zone2) -> {
                               zone1.getParts().addAll(zone2.getParts());
                               return zone1;
                             }));
```

Comment: Thanks Amardeep. While this helps to group by Id, what I need is to have the parts of the same zone merged so that I end up with one zone with aggregated parts in it's "parts" attribute.  With the current approach, I end up with a key with 2 zone values whcih have the same zone Id.

Comment: @RamViswanathan yeah, I have updated my answer. Now you would have the Zones with the same zone Ids having merged Parts if there is an Id match between two zones.

Comment: Thanks Amardeep, this is exactly what I was looking for. Works like a charm!

Comment: how do i accept an answer ? It did solve my problem.

Comment: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I was looking for the same thing.
Can you accept the answer @RamViswanathan?